# How do I move UINavigationBar under status bar and keep height for landscape and horizontal iPhone?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I have added `UINavigationBar` to `UIView` with custom `backgroundColor` and all I need to achieve is:

- the same background for status bar when it is displayed
- always the same height for UINavigationBar for both cases: status bar is displayed or not.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple solution:

Just add four magic constraints in your storyboard:

[image]

The most interesting constraint is the last one. How do we add it?

- move your `UINavigationBar` some points from the top (leave the space between your bar and top layout guide)
- simply add constraint (ctrl + drag) from your bar to **top layout guide** and set its constant to 44.
- then edit just added constraint, and change first item from top to bottom like in the image below:

[image]